# What are the limitations of partial indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, filtered-index, partial-index

The latest version of MongoDB (v3.2) adds support for [partial (filtered) indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/). You supply a filter when you create the index and that filter determines which documents will be referenced in the index and which will not.

Can I use any filter expression (as long as it's a valid filter)? Or are there limitations to the filter being used? If so, what are those limitations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Can I use any filter expression?

No, partial indexes support only a subset of the operators in the filter used. The only supported operators are: `$AND` (only at the top level), `$EQ`, `$LT`, `$LTE`, `$GT`, `$GTE`, `$EXISTS` and the `TYPE_OPERATOR`.

That leaves out, for example `$NOT`, `$REGEX`, `$OR`, etc.

You can see that in the source for MongoDB [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/69dec2fe8fed6d32ec4998ea7ec7ab063cb5b788/src/mongo/db/catalog/index_catalog.cpp#L422).

> What are those limitations?

There are also some general limitations on partial indexes:

- `_id` indexes can't be partial indexes.
- Sparse indexes can't be partial indexes.
- Shard key indexes can't be partial indexes.
- Partial indexes aren't supported in versions earlier than 3.2.

Comment: It doesn't appear that this can be accomplished from the C# driver.  At least I don't see PartialIndexFilter as a property of the CreateIndexOptions class

Comment: @RalphShillington How about [`PartialFilterExpression`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_CreateIndexOptions_1_PartialFilterExpression.htm)?

Comment: @i3amon You're absolutely right!  My error was in doing var options = new CreateIndexOptions();  without setting the generic type.

Comment: Is it possible to make a second `_id` index that would be partial (with a different name) ? (I'm trying to make some sort of default filter view which would automatically exclude blacklisted content)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that only `{ $exists: true }` is supported, because `{ $exists: false }` is translated internally to an expression which uses the `$not` operator, which itself is not supported.

Comment: As a workaround, instead of `{ $exists: false }` I think one can use `{ $eq: null }` which evaluates true when the field has the value `null` *or* if the field does not exist. Not identical behaviour, but close enough to build a partial index correctly.