# Mongo Partial Compound Unique Index | Not Used In Query

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a strange issue. I have a **partial, compound, unique** index with defination:

`createIndex({a: 1, b:1, c: 1}, {unique:1, partialFilterExpression: {c: {$type: "string"}}})`

Now when I perform a query this index is never used as per the explain plan. Even though there are document(s) matching the query.

Chaning same index to sparse instead of partial fixes the above issue, but **sparse, compound, unique** indexes have following issue: 
[dealing-with-mongodb-unique-sparse-compound-indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183109/dealing-with-mongodb-unique-sparse-compound-indexes)

[image: Index Is Properly Created]

[image: Query returns a document]

[image: Index is not Used]

Comment: Well if there is only one item in the collection this is hardly surprising. The Atlas tool is probably not the best place to be looking anyway. Instead you should look at the full result in the shell with `.explain(true)`. This will likely show that even though the index was "considered" it was discarded in favor of a collection scan for the single result.

Comment: Actually there are multiple items in collections. As you can see documents examined:5. This happens on larger collections as well.

Comment: Do you think you could show a more "complete" example then? And while you are at it, please actually use the `mongo` "shell" and include the "text" output here instead of pictures. Really hard to read pictures in a post, when "text" is so much clearer, and we can all copy and paste data and output. Which is something else you cannot do with pictures.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the [query coverage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#query-coverage) documentation for partial indexes:

> MongoDB will not use the partial index for a query or sort operation if using the index results in an incomplete result set.
>
> To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression (or a modified filter expression that specifies a subset of the filter expression) as part of its query condition.

In your set up you create a partial index filtering on `{c: {$type: "string"}}`.

Your query conditions are `{a:"1", b:"p", c:"2"}`, or a query shape of three equality comparisons (`{a: eq, b: eq, c: eq}`). Since this query shape does not include a `$type` filter on `c`,  the [query planner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) has to consider that queries fitting the shape should match values of any data type and the partial index is not a viable candidate for complete results.

Some example queries that would use your partial index (tested with MongoDB 3.4.5):

```
// Search on {a, b} with c criteria matching the index filter
db.mydb.find({a:"1", b:"p", c: { $type: "string" } })

// Search on {a,b,c} and use $and to include the type of c
db.mydb.find({a:"1", b:"p", $and: [{ c: "2"} , {c: { $type: "string" }}]})
```